# Group by ID, only where another column has the same value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to GROUP BY CAT_ID, but only show results WHERE GROUP_ID is only = 1. If it has 1 and other values for that unique CAT_ID, I don't want to include it.

```
GROUP_ID  CAT_ID
1         1 
1         1
1         1
2         1
3         1
3         1
1         2
1         2
1         3
2         3
```

So in this case the results would be:

```
CAT_ID
2
```

Since CAT_ID 2 is the only grouping where GROUP_ID is all 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
select cat_id
from t
group by cat_id
having max(group_id) = 1;
```

The above answers your question because you are looking for the minimum `group_id`.  A more general solution is:

```
having min(group_id) = max(group_id) and max(group_id) = 1;
```